# Using Fragments to switch activities

Tags: android, android-fragments, footer

I'm trying to create a layout that has a stationary footer with activities that slide behind it. I've been told to use Fragments, but that would mean that I would have to convert my already existing Activities to Fragments - right? Here is a diagram of what I'm trying to achieve: https://i.stack.imgur.com/16BeS.jpg

Comment: Extend your existing activity from FragmentActivity and replace your activity2 and activity3 with fragments.

Comment: @TarunMaheshwari Sorry, what I meant was: Activities 1, 2 and 3 can move back and forth inside of a container. Their movement is triggered by buttons 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: @TarunMaheshwari I still need help with this :) I don't want to replace the activities or have to recode them. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think @TarunMaheshwari is trying to say is that instead of having 3 activities (eg. classes with `extends activity`), replace it with `extends fragment` (obviously there are other minor changes you might have to make for the code to work) and then create a main activity (with `extends FragmentActivity`) that has the static footer you want which can call on the 3 different fragments.

Recommended readings:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html

http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html

Comment: This is a very good example to implement fragments. [Fragments, Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html#fragments)

Answer (score 0):

I believe using fragments is the right solution for your app. However, from what I understand from your question and comments, you really want to avoid using them. To use activities instead of fragments, implement a Tab Layout with a Tab Host and Tab Widget as explained in this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html). This solution allows you to use the tabs to switch between activities.

To align the Tab Host to the bottom of the screen, have a look at this [tutorial](http://envyandroid.com/archives/326/align-tabhost-at-bottom).